# Subtract first year's value from each grouped row in data frame

Tags: r

I need help from R experts in this community:
    set.seed(1234)
    x <- data.frame(id=1:5, value1=sample(1:5,5,replace=T), value2=sample(1:5,5), year=1)
    y <- data.frame(id=1:5, value1=sample(1:10,5), value2=sample(1:5,5), year=2)
    z <- data.frame(id=sample(1:4,3), value1=sample(1:10,3), value2=sample(1:5,3), year=3)
    f <- data.frame(id=sample(1:2,2), value1=sample(1:10,2), value2=sample(1:5,2), year=4)
    (df <- rbind(x, y, z,f))
    df1 <- df[order(df$id,df$year),]
    df1
       id value1 value2 year
        1      1      4    1
        1     10      1    2
        1      2      4    3
        1      3      3    4
        2      4      1    1
        2      2      3    2
        2      1      3    3
        2     10      1    4
        3      4      5    1
        3      3      5    2
        3      7      5    3
        4      4      2    1
        4      9      2    2
        5      5      3    1
        5      7      4    2

I want to get this output:

```
id value1 value2 year
 1     9     -3    2
 1     1      0    3
 1     2     -1    4
 2    -2      2    2
 2    -3      2    3
 2     6      0    4
 3    -1      0    2
 3     3      0    3
 4     5      0    2
 5     2      1    2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your code doesn't run for me, the definitions of x,y give `Error in data.frame(id = 1:4, value1 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = T), value2 = sample(1:5,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5, 1`

Comment: Sorry, it should go 5 for ID,

Comment: Please fix your code above to be reproducible. Always test it runs before you post it. (see "What is a MCVE?")

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by 'id', use `mutate_at` to do the difference between the values and where 'year' is 1 on the 'value' columns and then `filter` out rows having 'year' as 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(value1:value2), funs(. -.[year == 1])) %>% 
   filter(year!= 1)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   id [5]
#      id value1 value2  year
#   <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
# 1     1      9     -3     2
# 2     1      1      0     3
# 3     1      2     -1     4
# 4     2     -2      2     2
# 5     2     -3      2     3
# 6     2      6      0     4
# 7     3     -1      0     2
# 8     3      3      0     3
# 9     4      5      0     2
#10     5      2      1     2
```

---

Or a similar logic with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - x[year == 1]),
      by = id, .SDcols = value1:value2][year != 1]
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
nm1 <- c('value1', 'value2')
df1[nm1] <- df1[nm1] -df1[df1$year==1, 
        nm1][rep(seq_along(unique(df1$id)), table(df1$id)),]
df1[df1$year != 1,]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), value1 = c(1L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
 10L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 7L), value2 = c(4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), year = c(1L, 2L, 
  3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class =
   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` (function to subset data frame by factor(s)) and have it call `subset` (to filter out year 1) and `within` (to recalculate columns). From there, `by` returns a list of data frames that you can bind altogether wtih `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

**Data**

```
txt = 'id value1 value2 year
1      1      4    1
1     10      1    2
1      2      4    3
1      3      3    4
2      4      1    1
2      2      3    2
2      1      3    3
2     10      1    4
3      4      5    1
3      3      5    2
3      7      5    3
4      4      2    1
4      9      2    2
5      5      3    1
5      7      4    2'

df1 <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

**Process**

```
df_list <- by(df1, df1$id, function(sub){      
  subset(
         within(sub, {        
             value1 <- value1 - value1[[1]] 
             value2 <- value2 - value2[[1]]           
         }), 
         year > 1
  )      
})

new_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, unname(df_list)),
                     row.names = NULL)    
new_df

#    id value1 value2 year
# 1   1      9     -3    2
# 2   1      1      0    3
# 3   1      2     -1    4
# 4   2     -2      2    2
# 5   2     -3      2    3
# 6   2      6      0    4
# 7   3     -1      0    2
# 8   3      3      0    3
# 9   4      5      0    2
# 10  5      2      1    2
```